¿Como puedo actualizar las htmltools de R de una version 0.5.7 a 0.5.8?
Me da un error y he restaurado la sesión de R varias veces y vuelto a instalar las htmltools y no me funciona. El error es el siguiente:
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.5.7 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.8 is required


¿Has probado hacer install.packages("htmltools")?

@PatricioMoracho si ya lo he probado y no se me actualiza

Bueno, entonces ahí esta realmente el problema, ¿Tienes un error? Es probable que te pida reiniciar la sesión, si es así permítelo.

@PatricioMoracho Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace 'htmltools' 0.5.7 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.8 is required
Calls:  ... is_bs_theme -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace, este es el error que me aparace al intentar compilar en html. Ya he probado: install.packages("htmltools") y he reiniciado la sesión y me sigue sin funcionar y tampoco se me actualiza la versión

De casualidad tienes abierta alguna solapa con un archivo Rmd? Te sugiero que inicies Rstudio y cierres todas las solapas, especialmente si apuntan a un archivo Rmarkdown, recién ahí prueba ejecutar install.packages("htmltools")

@PatricioMoracho si era eso, tenía abierto un rmarkdown, muchas gracias!
